# Julia HTTP POST request with image attachment

Tags: http, post, request, julia, pushover

I'm struggling implementing a POST request with image attachment with the Julia [HTTP package](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl). In Python I can do (source from [Pushover](https://support.pushover.net/i44-example-code-and-pushover-libraries#python)):

```
import requests
r = requests.post("https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json", data = {
  "token": "APP_TOKEN",
  "user": "USER_KEY"
},
files = {
  "attachment": ("image.jpg", open("myimage.jpg", "rb"), "image/jpeg")
})
```

How can I do such a file attachment in simple ways with Julia/HTTP or another Julia package?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the equivalent request using [`HTTP.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl):

```
import HTTP
url = "http://localhost:8080" # check request with e.g. netcat -lp 8080
open("cat.jpg") do io
    headers = []
    data = [
        "token" => "APP_TOKEN",
        "user" => "USER_KEY",
        "attachment" => io,
    ]
    body = HTTP.Form(data)
    HTTP.post(url, headers, body)
end
```

The filename (`cat.jpg`) and content type (`image/jpeg`) is inferred from the `io`.

---

If you need better control, for example if you want the filename in the request to differ from the filename on disk, or if you want to manually specify `Content-Type`, you can manually construct a `HTTP.Multipart` entry, like this:

```
data = [
    "token" => "APP_TOKEN",
    "user" => "USER_KEY",
    "attachment" => HTTP.Multipart("other_filename.jpg", io, "image/png"),
]
```

---

You can compare/verify the request from `HTTP.jl` with the one from `requests` by using something like

```
$ netcat -lp 8080
```

and send the requests to `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed example and explanation. Works perfectly.